# Запрос с 4-х уровневой выборкой

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть 4 таблицы связанные между собой по id иерархически юзеры->телефоны->сайты->налог и есть входящий массив данных в котором присутствует столбец вида
 `site.ru`
`site2.ru`
`site3.ru`
`123456`
`8967654`
`456876`
 У каждого пользователя есть также столбец с денежным счетом. Как составить запрос что бы перебирало входящий массив и при совпадении данных со столбца с привязанными данными к каждому юзеру (номер телефона или сайт) снимало с его счета налог забитый в таблице налогов (налог привязан только к сайту). Никак не придумаю такой перебор с одновременным сравнением и обновлением данных по счету. Если есть уточняющие вопросы спрашивайте может дал неполную картину.
 Вот что вышло в результате:

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (1,2)");
while ($sub_money2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
    $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT users.id, users.money, phones.phone, site.url, rates.taxes FROM users LEFT JOIN phones ON users.id = phones.user_id LEFT JOIN site ON phones.id = site.phones_id LEFT JOIN rates ON site.id = rates.site_id WHERE users.id = {$sub_money2['id']}");
    while ($sub_money3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)) {
        $sub3_result[] = $sub_money3;
        foreach ($sub1_emailFrom as $sub1) {
            foreach ($sub3_result as $sub3) {
                if (($sub3['phone'] == $sub1) || ($sub3['url'] == $sub1)) {
                    $query4 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money = ({$sub3['money']} - {$sub3['taxes']}) WHERE users.id = {$sub3['id']}");
                    echo "Обновление у юзера:" . $sub3['id'] . " баланс равен:" . $sub3['money'] . "<br/>";

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Остался только вопрос как сделать так что бы после каждой успешного ифа (тобишь когда средства снялись со чета баланс обновлялся и в дальшейшем средства снимались с нового баланса сейчас же идет снятие каждый раз с начальной суммы)

Comment: Для начала сделайте обычный select который выбирает данные из этих таблиц. Надо же от чего то отталкиваться. Потому к этому select дописать пачку условий как бы вы проверяли подходящие записи (для одного значения) что то типа `"site.ru" in(table_a.site, table_b.phone,...)`. А потом уже это преобразовывать в update ....

Comment: _при совпадении данных со столбца с привязанными данными к каждому юзеру (номер телефона или сайт) снимало с его счета налог забитый в таблице налогов (налог привязан только к сайту)._ Налог привязан только к сайту, а снимать его и за сайт, и за телефон?

Comment: _сделать так что бы после каждой успешного ифа (тобишь когда средства снялись со чета баланс обновлялся и в дальшейшем средства снимались с нового баланса сейчас же идет снятие каждый раз с начальной суммы_ То есть Вы в таблице данных пользователя храните и постоянно пересчитываете актуальное состояние его счёта??? как говорил один политик, "Нет слов, чтобы выразиться!"... тут вроде не принято, но на многих ресурсах, увидев подобное, начинают рекомендовать сменить работу.

Comment: Суть нее в этом какое было тз так и сделал. Снятие нормально проходит и за сайт и за телефон вопрос в том как сделать что бы после каждого снятие баланс обновлялся и снималось у же дальше с нового баланса.